# Inside Eclipse PDT whats the purpose of "PHP include path" in project properties?

Tags: php, eclipse, properties, eclipse-pdt, include-path

Was wondering when we right click on project folder in php explorer then there is an option "Php include path" it does not edit include_path property of php.ini . Hence even specifying include path using this option it does no different to project then whats its purpose of it??

Comment: Do you test it via a webserver, or with the built in "Run as script"?

Comment: @kingCrunch I tested it through webserver since its an web project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webserver (more accurate: The interpreter process created by the webserver) cannot know, that you even use an IDE to write your scripts, so its also impossible for it to know the project settings. If you execute it from within eclipse, it provides a custom `php.ini`, that contains the given include-path.

Answer (score 2):

Its is used to link two projects together within eclipse. If one project includes code from another project, eclipse is not aware of the connection and only evaluates the code with the project you are in. So if you try and use a function from another project for example, there would be no auto complete etc for that function.

By adding the second project to your include_path you are telling eclipse that you are using that project and all that projects classes, functions etc will be added to the auto complete and documentation prompt.

You are still required to connect the two by code.

Comment: yes I was also thinking the same it should be changed to autcomplete_path to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thats not entirely true. If you execute a script via "Run as script", than eclipse provides its own `php.ini` with the include-path from the projects properties. However, if you execute the same script from external (and a webserver is an external caller), the interpreter simply doesnt know, that you even use eclipse.